# mvc.net get profile info from twitter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, twitter

I'm trying to retrieve profile information from Twitter after authenticating using standard mvc.net external authentication.

I can do this for facebook using the below code (needs Facebook SDK installed) located in the ExternalLoginCallback function.

```
 if (string.Equals(loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider, "facebook", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var access_token = identity.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken");
            var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            // you need to specify all the fields that you want to get back
            dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name");
            email = myInfo.email;
            firstName = myInfo.first_name;
            lastName = myInfo.last_name;
        }
```

I am looking for a twitter equivalent.

TIA

Comment: Check https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries.html for options . Recommendation: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/

Comment: @Mate thx for the links. Have installed TweetinviAPI as sugested but struggling to find the code I need to replicate the facebook example above. Having looked a little deeper at Twitter I think the best I can hope for is the email address but thats still a win for me. :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad helped you. If you need a "public" url for callbacks,  use ngrok ( https://ngrok.com/ ) it's the best tool for that.  Also, you could mark as accepted your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did based largely on this

[Obtain twitter access token asp.net identity](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2014/03/16/obtaining-twitter-access-tokens-with-asp.net-identity.aspx)

First, i installed the [TwitterinviAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/)  nuget package as per @Mate suggestion above.

Second, i updated the twitter section of ConfigureAuth in StartUp.Auth.cs to include a "Provider"

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"],
            ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"],
            Provider = new LinqToTwitterAuthenticationProvider(),
            BackchannelCertificateValidator = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
                {
                   "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
                   "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
                   "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
                   "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
                   "‎add53f6680fe66e383cbac3e60922e3b4c412bed", // Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
                   "4eb6d578499b1ccf5f581ead56be3d9b6744a5e5", // VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5
                   "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", // DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A 
                   "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3" // DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
                 }),
        });
```

Third, I added the LinqToTwitterAuthenticationProvider Class to Model/IdentityModels (though you can put this code anywhere you like)

```
public class LinqToTwitterAuthenticationProvider : TwitterAuthenticationProvider
{
    public const string AccessToken = "TwitterAccessToken";
    public const string AccessTokenSecret = "TwitterAccessTokenSecret";

    public override Task Authenticated(TwitterAuthenticatedContext context)
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaims(
            new List<Claim>
            {
            new Claim(AccessToken, context.AccessToken),
            new Claim(AccessTokenSecret, context.AccessTokenSecret)
            });

        return base.Authenticated(context);
    }
```

Lastly, I updated ExternalLoginCallback in the Accounts controller with the following code to get the user details from twitter

```
  else if (string.Equals(loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider, "twitter", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Generate credentials that we want to use
            var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var access_token = identity.FindFirstValue(LinqToTwitterAuthenticationProvider.AccessToken);
            var access_token_secret = identity.FindFirstValue(LinqToTwitterAuthenticationProvider.AccessTokenSecret);
            var creds = new TwitterCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"],access_token, access_token_secret);
            var authenticatedUser = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser(creds);
            email = authenticatedUser.Email;
            firstName = authenticatedUser.Name.Substring(0, authenticatedUser.Name.IndexOf(' '));
            lastName = authenticatedUser.Name.Substring(authenticatedUser.Name.IndexOf(' ') + 1);

        }
```

There was one little GOTCHYA. Email was coming through as null even after all this. The problem was in my twitter app set up I had not supplied a privacy or ToS URL and hence could not check the option under the permissions tab to request users email. Just a freindly FYI.

Hope this helps!!